# Twitter 'Faves' Widget - RPP Value

Tags: twitter

I'm using the 'faves' widget for a moderated twitter feed. I'm just wondering what affect the 'rpp' value has here.

It's set to poll for new results and load tweets at 30 second intervals. Just wondering what my RPP value should be here

(I want it to continue polling new tweets as long as they are coming.)

Thanks

BIOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RPP stands for "[Results Per Page](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/6681)".  So, it depends on how many results you want to get.

The search API is capped at 100 RPP.